# Yii framework, bootstrap widget BootTabbable does not work with Chrome or Safari

Tags: google-chrome, safari, yii, twitter-bootstrap, yii-extensions

I am using [bootstrap extention](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/bootstrap/) with Yii framework to have tabs for the content. [Here is an example](http://marionette-cola.linkmesrl.com/compania/viewstoria). The tabs work fine in firefox, however in Google Chrome and Safari the tabs behave differently, they load with the page load but after clicking on the tabs they get selectet but the content does not show.

Here is the code for these tabs:

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.BootTabbable', array(
                'type'=>'tabs', // 'tabs' or 'pills'
                'tabs'=>array(
                        array('label'=>'Marionettisti', 'content'=>$this->renderPartial('staff/_view_staff_marionettisti', array('model'=>$model),$this),'active'=>true),
                        array('label'=>'Voci e Musica', 'content'=>$this->renderPartial('staff/_view_staff_vociemusica', array('model'=>$model),$this)),
                        array('label'=>'Laboratorio', 'content'=>$this->renderPartial('staff/_view_staff_laboratorio', array('model'=>$model),$this)),
                        array('label'=>'Direttore Artistico', 'content'=>$this->renderPartial('staff/_view_staff_direttore_artistico', array('model'=>$model),$this)),
                ),
            )); ?>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

try passing third and forth element true in renderPartial such as

```
$this->renderPartial('staff/_view_staff_marionettisti', array('model'=>$model),true,true
```

Comment: No, it didn't work, I think it has something to do with this: In Firefox, when you click on something, it seems to gain focus but that does not seem to be true for Chrome in this case.

Comment: Try adding `<div class="clear-fix"></div>` at the end of rendered page. If content is there for first time then it is there just matter of divs or something.Currently I am working on project that involves Tabs and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

check whether all of our div is correctly closed in rendered pages. i was having same problem error was unappropriately closing div